# rails ネストした子モデルのバリデーションの方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### やりたいこと

掲示板：コメントが１対多のような関係で、以下のような掲示板で、コメント欄が空白のまま投稿しようとすると、バリデーションエラーメッセージを表示したい。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 設定

親モデル（Board）
カラム：title
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

子モデル(Comment)
カラム
board_id ##外部キー
user_name
content

belongs_to :board
validates :content, presence: true

view

```
%h2= t '.title'
  = link_to "#{t '.back_to_index'}", boards_path
  .thread-title
    = @board.title
  %hr
  - @comments.each_with_index do |comment, i|
    .field
      = "#{i+1}"
      = ":"
      = comment.user_name
      = comment.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      - if current_user.id == comment.user_id
        = link_to "#{t '.edit'}", edit_comment_path(comment)
        = link_to "#{t '.delete'}", comment_path(comment), method: :delete
    .field
      = comment.content
    %hr
= form_for([@board, @comment]) do |f|
  = render 'shared/errors', object: @comment
  .field
    = f.label :"#{t '.content'}"
    = f.text_area :content, rows: "5", class: "form-control"
    = f.hidden_field :user_name, value:current_user.name
    = f.hidden_field :board_id
  .button-field
    = f.submit "#{t '.create_comment'}", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

メッセージ表示view

```
- if object.errors.any?
  #error_explanation.alert.alert-danger
    %ul
    - object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      %li= msg
```

### 質問

Commentモデルのcontentカラムにバリデーションをかけただけだと何も反応しませんでした。
メッセージ表示に渡すオブジェクトは、@commentでいいのかというのも疑問です。
この場合、バリデーションでメッセージを表示するには、どのような設定が必要でしょうか。

Comment: コントローラーのコードも記載してください

Answer (score 2):

[validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) ですかね。

```
class Board < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :comments, associated: true
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :board
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

で、 rails console でこんな感じになりますね。

```
>> b = Board.create(title: 'test')
>> b.valid?
=> true # コメントがない状態なので
>> b.comments.create(user_name: 'anonymous') # create なので valid ならセーブされるはず
>> b.comments.first.new_record?
=> true # セーブされてない
>> Comment.count
=> 0
>> b.valid?
=> false # comment が valid ではないため
```

同じようになるのにフォーム経由だとそうならないなら、フォーム/コントローラでの処理を確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記コードをBoardに追加しても、バリデーションかからず、空白でコメントが投稿できてしまいました。他に何か設定が必要でしょうか。

Comment: コンソールでの確認結果を追記。httpを通しての動作は準備が面倒なのでやってません。